# Statusmessage using my android facebook app

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

Actually I am pretty new in this , so this question might seems a little bit stupid for many of you.
Anyway here is goes:

I am creating this app on android which is supposed to take the input from a edittext field and post it to facebook page wall.

Now I have this code, but it s`hows mfacebook.**dialog**(this, "stream.publish", params, this);`
 has an error saying : 
`The method dialog(Context, String, Bundle, Facebook.DialogListener) in the type Facebook is not applicable for the arguments (new View.OnClickListener(){}, String, Bundle, new View.OnClickListener(){})`.

Can somebody please tell me what is wrong?

```
public class FetchData extends Activity {

private Facebook mfacebook;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_fetch_data);
    final Button widget45 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.widget45);
    final Button widget44 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.widget44);
    final Button imageButton2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
    final Button imageButton1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
    final ImageButton widget48 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.widget48);
    final ImageButton widget49 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.widget49);
    final ImageButton widget51 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.widget51);
    final ImageButton widget56 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.widget56);
    final EditText widget40 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.widget40);
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .
    imageButton1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //To change body of implemented methods use File | Settings | File Templates.

            mfacebook = new Facebook("558718227474980");
            Bundle params = new Bundle();
            params.putString("message", widget40.getText().toString());
            mfacebook.dialog(this, "stream.publish", params, this);
        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: Are you using Android Facebook SDK for this?

Comment: Yes "adt-bundle-windows" from google with the facebook adk provided by facebook!